# Referencing the Current Context in a T-SQL nodes() XQuery

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

Is it possible to effect a join between two T-SQL `nodes()` calls by filtering the second `nodes()` based on the context node of the first?

In the example below, I'm trying to return a table showing `PersonID`, `Name` and `Position`. My attempt at referencing the `@id` of the first `nodes()`'s context node in the second `nodes()` XQuery statement doesn't work. No position names are returned.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

```
DECLARE @xml xml  = '<Root>
    <People>
        <Person id="1">Frank</Person>
        <Person id="2">Joe</Person>
    </People>
    <Positions>
        <Position assignedToPerson="1">Engineer</Position>
        <Position assignedToPerson="2">Manager</Position>
    </Positions>
</Root>'

SELECT 
   PersonID = person.value('@id', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
   Name = person.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
   positionTitle = position.value('Position[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
FROM 
   @xml.nodes('/Root/People/Person') People(person)
OUTER APPLY 
   @xml.nodes('/Root/Positions/Position[@assignedToPerson=.[@id]]') Positions(position)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using join by value instead of cross apply by node should work; positiontitle in the projection then becomes the element value (.):

```
DECLARE @xml xml  = '<Root>
    <People>
        <Person id="1">Frank</Person>
        <Person id="2">Joe</Person>
    </People>
    <Positions>
        <Position assignedToPerson="1">Engineer</Position>
        <Position assignedToPerson="2">Manager</Position>
    </Positions>
</Root>'

SELECT 
   PersonID = person.value('@id', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
   Name = person.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
   positionTitle = position.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
FROM 
   @xml.nodes('/Root/People/Person') People(person)
JOIN 
   @xml.nodes('/Root/Positions/Position') Positions(position)
ON person.value('@id', 'NVARCHAR(50)')= 
position.value('@assignedToPerson[1]','NVARCHAR(50)')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Jayvee! It doesn't look like what I hoped to do (reference the previous nodes() context from within a nodes() XQUERY) is possible. Your answer solves the larger need--joining the two document parts--so I'll award it the answer check.

Answer (score 2):

Some minor changes here and there but pretty much same as what Jayvee has written. I have applied LEFT JOIN to ensure OUTER APPLY logic is met

```
DECLARE @xml xml  = '<Root>
    <People>
        <Person id="1">Frank</Person>
        <Person id="2">Joe</Person>
        <Person id="3">Joe No Manager</Person>
    </People>
    <Positions>
        <Position assignedToPerson="1">Engineer</Position>
        <Position assignedToPerson="2">Manager</Position>
    </Positions>
</Root>'

SELECT   person.value('@id', 'INT') AS PersonID,
         person.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS NAME,
         position.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS positionTitle
FROM     @xml.nodes('/Root/People/Person') People(person)
LEFT JOIN    @xml.nodes('/Root/Positions/Position') Positions(position)
    ON   person.value('@id', 'INT') = position.value('@assignedToPerson', 'INT')
```